# Merge Python List

Tags: python, list

I have a list

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]
```

Result

```
New_a = [[1,3,5,7,9],[2,4,6,8,10]]
```

Any smart way or python built-in function can solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]])
```

Result:

```
>>> a
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 3,  4],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 7,  8],
       [ 9, 10]])
>>> a.T
array([[ 1,  3,  5,  7,  9],
       [ 2,  4,  6,  8, 10]])
```

Comment: Matrixbots!  Transpose and move out!

Answer (score 7):

```
list(zip(*a))
Out[6]: [(1, 3, 5, 7, 9), (2, 4, 6, 8, 10)]
```

Explanation: `zip` takes two or more iterables and stitches them together where "the i-th element comes from the i-th iterable argument."  The star operator unpacks `a` so that you zip the *elements* together, not the sublists.

Comment: why do you need `list`?

Comment: @lukas in python3 `zip` returns a generator object.  You can drop the `list` in python2.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` in conjunction with the flattening operator `*`:

```
[list(t) for t in zip(*a)]
```

You could also just use `zip(*a)` by itself if (1) you're using Python 2 and (2) you don't mind getting a list of tuples instead of a list of lists.